# Can a hidden variable theory be seen as a map from unitaries to stochastics with the same dimensions?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, quantum-computer

In [Quantum Computing in Hidden Variables](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.71.032325), Scott Aaronson defines a hidden variable theory as something that transforms a unitary matrix mapping $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1 & \ldots & \alpha_n\end{bmatrix}^T \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}\beta_1 & \ldots & \beta_n\end{bmatrix}^T$ to a stochastic matrix mapping $\begin{bmatrix}|\alpha_1|^2 & \ldots & |\alpha_n|^2\end{bmatrix}^T \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}|\beta_1|^2 & \ldots & |\beta_n|^2\end{bmatrix}^T$. The way he writes, this is apparently a fairly established way of viewing hidden variable theories, but it seems strangely restrictive to me.

Isn't the point of a hidden variable theory that there are degrees of freedom beyond the observable probability distribution?  Shouldn't such a theory map $n\times n$ unitaries to $(n+k)\times (n+k)$ stochastic matrices for some $k$?  Aaronson's stipulation that $k = 0$ forces the stochastic matrix to work on a representation that e.g. has lost the distinction between $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$, which makes some of the pathologies he discusses seem like artifacts of this stipulation than something about hidden variables in general.

Is Aaronson's definition actually in line with how a physicist views hidden variable theories?  If so, what would justify discounting the expansion of the state vector with additional entries?

PS.  I'm a computer scientist by training, so I might be ignorant of something that's really basic to a physicist.

Comment: *Is Aaronson's definition actually in line with how a physicist views hidden variable theories?* -- No. (The way you state it.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch That's good to know.  But isn't it at least a reasonable simplification of the physicist's understanding of hidden variable theories?  Surely some physicists would have had a pass over this paper before publication on Physical Review?